# Explanation of the use of the __call__ method in dateutil.rrule's rrulestr() method

Tags: python

Python's [dateutil.rrule](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html?highlight=rrule) module has an `rrule` object with a custom `__str__` method, as well as a method `rrulestr` which performs the inverse operation, namely, reconstruct an `rrule` object from its string representation. Here is an illustration of its use:

```
In [1]: from dateutil.rrule import *

In [2]: my_rrule = rrule(DAILY, count=2)

In [3]: list(my_rrule)
Out[3]: 
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 25, 19, 58, 40),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 26, 19, 58, 40)]

In [4]: list(rrulestr(str(my_rrule)))
Out[4]: 
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 25, 19, 58, 40),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 26, 19, 58, 40)]
```

I would like to do something similar with a different object, so I'm trying to understand how this is implement in rrule's [source code](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/dateutil/rrule.html#rrule). Here is a 'condensed' excerpt of what it contains:

```
class _rrulestr(object):

    def _parse_rfc(self, s,
                   dtstart=None,
                   cache=False,
                   unfold=False,
                   forceset=False,
                   compatible=False,
                   ignoretz=False,
                   tzinfos=None):
        global parser

    def __call__(self, s, **kwargs):
        return self._parse_rfc(s, **kwargs)

rrulestr = _rrulestr()
```

As I understand it, the `__call__` method defined for the `_rrulestr` class makes it essentially behave like a function. What is the advantage of this approach? Why not just define `rrulestr` as a function directly? And can someone explain to me step by step how this works?

**P.S.** I'm also having problems imitating this style of a 'callable class'. For example, if I try

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5

class CallableClass(object):
    def __call__(self, arg):
        return arg

print(CallableClass("Hello"))
```

I get a `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kurt/Documents/Scratch/call_test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(CallableClass("Hello"))
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

but I don't see how this example is so different from `_rrulestr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of a "callable class" is that it's the *instance* that is callable. Of course, any class is callable in the sense that calling a class gives you an instance; but defining the `__call__` method means that the resulting instance is also callable.

So, your code should be:

```
print(CallableClass()("Hello"))
```

As you can see, the `rrule` module defines its instance at the end: `rrulestr = _rrulestr()` - and it is that object that you call.